# An object property value does not update

Tags: javascript

At some point in my JavaScript app I add objects with `myData.isStarted` property value set to true to a map and run a loop that checks this property value of the objects I added with a code like this:

```
class Application
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.exchanges = new Map();
    }

    getExchange(exchangeId)
    {
        let exchange = this.exchanges.get(exchangeId);
        this.ensure(exchange, `Exchange '${exchangeId}' not found in the map.`);
        return exchange;
    }

    async createExchanges()
    {
        let exchange = new SomeClass();

        this.ensure(!exchange.myData, 'Property exchange.myData already exists.');
        exchange.myData = {isStarted: true};

        this.exchanges.set(row.exchangeId, exchange);

        this.runWorker(exchange).then(result => this.logInfo(`'${runWorker}' has returned '${result}'.`)).catch(e => this.traceException(e));
    }

    async runWorker(exchange)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            while (!exchange.myData.isStarted)
            {
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
            }

            //do something else here
        }
    }
}
```

at some other point in my code I set the value of `myData.isStated` to false:

```
async handleCommand(command, params)
{
    //...
    const exchange = this.getExchange(params.exchangeId);
    exchange.myData.isStarted = false;
}
```

this code works fine, but `myData.isStarted` property stops updating if I change the code to this:

```
    async runWorker()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            while (!someSavedReferenceToExchange.myData.isStarted)
            {
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
            }

            //do something else here
        }
    }
```

where `someSavedReferenceToExchange` is a reference to the object assigned with

```
someSavedReferenceToExchange = this.getExchange(someId);
```

at some other point in my code (that is stored in an object that is an element of an array etc...).

1) What can be wrong?

2) How to check if `someSavedReferenceToExchange` references an object from the map, but not store its copy, for example?

Comment: You can check if `Array.from(this.exchanges.values()).includes(someSavedReferenceToExchange)`. Is `createExchanges` maybe called more than once? Try checking that `!this.exchanges.has(row.exchangeId)` before setting (and similar before setting anywhere).

Comment: Where exactly is `someSavedReferenceToExchange` saved? Notice that currently your *local variable* `exchange` is just a saved reference as well. It's not clear what exactly you would be doing differently.

Comment: @Ry- Storing the `exchangeId` on the `exchange` object itself, and then logging `someSavedReferenceToExchange.id` might also be a good idea to debug this

Answer (score 1):

As Ry- noticed in the comments `createExchanges()` was called multiple times.